# Edittext content is displaying zero

Tags: java, android

I am making an application where i need to take the input from the user and append that input with the string and use that as a url for data parsing
But the edit text content is null even though i am entering text in edittext
I converted edittext content to string as below

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.Id.tv5);
```

And inside onclicklistener

```
String data = edit.getText().toString();
```

Can anybody tell me why the `data.length()` is giving me zero?
my complete main activity is below:

```
public class Pnr extends Activity {
EditText edit;
TextView text1;
Button button;
String pnr, check;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
int s;
String URL = "pnrbuddy.com/pnrstatus=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pnr);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv5);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    pnr = String.valueOf(edit.getText());
    s = pnr.length();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Read().execute("trainNo");

        }
    });
}

public JSONObject pnrStatus(String key) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(key);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    JSONObject last = new JSONObject();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        last = new JSONObject(data);
        return last;
    } else {
        return last;
    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            json = pnrStatus(pnr);
            return json.getString(arg0[0]);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return s + "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text1.setText("               " + result);

    }

}
```

}
when i enter the string instead of accepting from edittext in the string URL along with the exsisting string the code works
URL="pnrbuddy/pnrstatus=myText";
why i m unable to get string from editText?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct id - tv5 ?

Comment: forget about my comment.. that was only available in TextView class

Comment: what does `System.out.println("you entered: "+data);` print in logcat?

Comment: @user3363800 show your Button click Listener code

Comment: Post your full Activity class code.

Comment: Could you show us some more code and your layout xml file?

Comment: @user3363800 Not like this way. Edit your code with full java class file here.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv5);
String data = edit.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are try to get length in `onclicklistener` in `EditText` it will give u `0` only.In this case try to get from `onTextChange`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your on create method by this n try

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pnr);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pnr =edit.getText().toString();
                s = pnr.length();
                new Read().execute("trainNo");

            }
        });
    }
```

Actually your getting text when the activity is created not when button is clicked, So placing the gettext code in onclick method would resolve your problem